# A function to find the minimum bounding pie slice to enclose a set of points

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, angle

I have a set of points S that I need to sort based on their angles around a point P. However, I want to avoid specifying a particular starting angle for sorting. My goal is to obtain an ordered set where the angle between the first and last points has the smallest possible value among all potential starting angles.

In essence, I am not concerned with the final sorted set of points; instead, I am seeking the angle of the smallest pie slice that can encompass all the points in the set.

How can I achieve this efficiently in C++? I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on the most effective approach to tackle this problem.

[image]

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can a question simply be moved? I was not aware there was a separate site for purely algorithmic questions.

Comment: If the whole point is to get "the angle of the smallest pie slice that can encompass all the points in the set", have you tried just finding what's the point with the largest angle from the center point, and the point with the smallest angle, and that's your answer?

Comment: Moderators can move.

Comment: "the angle between the first and last points has the smallest possible value among all potential starting angles." - if the centre of the pie can be anywhere, then just take it far to the left and you can make the angle as small as you like! If the centre of the pie is fixed then just take the largest and smallest angles. Your question doesn't seem to be well-posed whichever site it should be on.

Comment: There is no such thing as an absolute *largest* or *smallest* angle. It depends on where you define your zero angle. For example for the above picture if you set zero to be the positive x axis you get a different answer to if you set zero to be the -ve y axis

Comment: @lastchance I should say given a fixed point to sort the points around. Updated the question. But you did give me an idea. Just pick any starting angle and sort. Then go through the list and compare all adjacent angles and return the largest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bring all angles into the range 0 to 2PI
2. Sort angles
3. Find the minimum covering angle over all pairs of adjacent angles.

The **covering angle** is defined as the angle of the traversal between two adjacent angles that would cover all other angles.

```cpp
template <typename T>
T AngleSpan(std::vector<T> angles)
{
    // First bring all angles into 0 to 2PI
    for (T angle : angles)
    {
        angle = Wrap2PI(angle);
    }

    if (angles.size() == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("The number of angles must have at least one angle");

    if(angles.size() == 1)
        return 0.;

    std::sort(angles.begin(), angles.end());
    // Push the start angle shifted forward by 360 degrees
    angles.push_back(angles.front() + 2 * PI);

    double coveringAngle = 2 * PI;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < angles.size(); ++i) {
        double testAngle = 2 * PI - angles[i] + angles[i - 1];
        if (testAngle < coveringAngle) {
            coveringAngle = testAngle;
        }
    }


    return coveringAngle;
}
```

Test cases and verification.

https://godbolt.org/z/v9vdWzbGK
(c++23 is used for test cases because of range support but the implementation of AngleSpan itself is c++17 )